# How to add CakePHP loggable behaviour to all Models, AppModel - without causing a loop?

Tags: cakephp

I've added loggable behaviour to the AppModel which then caused a loop - as Log extends AppModel.

Is there a way to "unload" Logable from the actsAs array from the Log model?

Comment: Maybe you should add it in __construct (if class name !== Log).

Comment: in AppModel or LogableBehaviour?

Comment: When adding it in your AppModel

Comment: if the loop is caused by callbacks when you save your data, then you can disable callbacks in the save statement options setting `'callbacks' => false`

Answer (score 1):

Per the [Behaviors page in the CakePHP Book](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/behaviors.html), you can disable a behavior from a specific model:

```
$this->Category->Behaviors->disable('Translate');
```